# Should one consider navigation bar when designing mockups for android?

Tags: android, adobe-xd

When designing mockups for android screens e.g (360x640p). Should the designer take into consideration the space the system navigation bar takes at the bottom?. In other words is the space covered by the system navigation bar of an android phone considered when talking about the " screen resolution " (by screen resolution I mean something like 360x640p)

Comment: `Should the designer take into consideration...` well, that's for the _designer_ to determine, isn't it ? :) we're developers here, so i don't think your question is on-topic here

Comment: As a beginner I'm kind of my own designer at this point that's why I wanted to know. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Do not take the system buttons for granted when creating mockups for an android screen.

The system buttons aren't always present. On some devices and android versions, users can choose to [show or hide those buttons](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9079644?hl=en).

Also, the available resolution for the screen changes when the system buttons are visible. Notice how the height changes which is returned by `context.resources.getDisplayMetrics()`:
[image]

Comment: With this information, how then can a designer use this in their mockup?

Comment: Don't rely on fixed screen resolutions. Always assume, that your content won't fit on small screens and that there will be plenty of whitespace on large screens. Keep in mind, that the aspect ratios also vary. Practically speaking, that means for example: Don't put to many elements horizontally next to each other in portrait mode. They probably won't fit. Don't put to many elements vertically next to each other if you want to avoid that the users need to scroll.